# iOS exploit hunting environment

Tags: disassembly, debugging, exploit, ios, fuzzing

Suppose, I have a new iPhone 6s with latest iOS, and I want to find vulnerabilities in iOS itself. iPhone is not jailbroken. How do I set up the proper environment for this? What software and/or hardware tools do I need to accomplish this?

P.S.: Which component of iOS would you recommend me to start with? Which one is more likely to contain vulnerabilities that could result in jailbreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reading this book to get some answers:-

iOS Hacker's Handbook
http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118204123.html

Covers iOS security architecture, vulnerability hunting, exploit writing, and how iOS jailbreaks work
Explores iOS enterprise and encryption, code signing and memory protection, sandboxing, iPhone fuzzing, exploitation, ROP payloads, and baseband attacks
Also examines kernel debugging and exploitation
Companion website includes source code and tools to facilitate your efforts